# I can't get images to show up in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, image, embedded-resource

I am fairly new to using Swing and I thought that in Eclipse all I would have to do is put an image file into the SRC directory and the program would have access to it.  Of course this is not the case.  The only way the image is accessed is by supplying the whole "C:" filename.  I tried putting it into a sub directory and added the folder to the build path.  I thought that would work.

My program is currently called "PullingMyHairOut" because that is exactly what I am doing.  If you answer, please assume that I have no idea of the internal workings of Eclipse because that isn't far from the truth.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class PullingHairOut extends JFrame{
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("us.jpg");
    JLabel label = new JLabel(img);

    public PullingHairOut(){
        setSize(640,480);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(label,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(new JButton("Help"),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PullingHairOut main = new PullingHairOut();
    }
}
```

Comment: Two things. 1- I believe in Eclipse resources need to be stored in the "resources" folder within the project, not "src"; 2- You will no longer be able to access these resources like they are files, but rather as resources. You will need to using something `getClass().getResource("/path/to/resource")`

Comment: Images typically go in your `res --> drawable xxxx` folders.

Comment: Gee.. I've never seen a problem quite like this before.  Well, except for twice earlier today, a couple of times yesterday, ..  Please **search** for solutions before presuming you have an unique problem.

Comment: The reason I did post it is because I found plenty of examples, but they were all using classes and methods that I haven't figured out just yet and I want to tackle one headache at a time.

Comment: Resources don't have to be stored in any particular spot to be used as a file.  If you don't want to load them using a fully qualified path, though, you need to check what the Working Directory is set to in your Java Application Launcher.  By default, it's the root of the project.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  What worked was
   ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("us.jpg"));
and put the image in the bin folder.  This makes sense in a way, but I have a feeling it isn't how it should be done.

Answer (score 2):

If you put the images in the source folder, you have to access it like this (if I remember correctly) :

```
src/us.jpg
```

This is because the current working directory starts out at the root folder. Then again, I may be wrong - the last time I loaded an image file using Eclipse was a few months ago.

Answer (score 0):

right click your project root to create a folder named "res". move your us.jpg to the folder. and modify your code `ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("res/us.jpg");`

Answer (score 0):

Read up on Class#getResource() and the ImageIcon(URL) constructor.  Stop thinking about it as a file, you'll make your application more flexible in the end.

TL;DR: For something in the root of your source folder, you should just be able to find a URL for it in the runtime classpath using Class#getResource("us.jpg") (called on one of your own classes) and feed the resulting URL into the ImageIcon constructor.